# How to Delete attribute VALUES?

Tags: import, magento-1.7, ce-1.5.1.0

Importing blank columns using "Replace" action does not result in deletion of attribute values.
Magento 1.5, 1.7

E.g. a csv containing a list of skus whose sale end date has passed to try to delete those dates and sale prices from the db does not work.

```
sku   | special_price | special_price_to_date
MX300 |               | 
MX301 |               |
MX302 |               |
```

etc...

Blank columns do not effect any change. So how do I delete values for a product attribute using import?

Comment: Are you having this problem only with the `special_price` columns or also with other attributes?

Comment: @FlorianIlgenfritz have not been able to delete any attribute values at all, only overwrite them.

Answer (score 1):

Your attributes are being filtered out by `array_filter()` in `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_filterRowData()`

Empty rows would be filtered out again in `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product_Type_Abstract::prepareAttributesForSave()` during `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_saveProducts()`

It therefore looks like the importer isn't built to handle this.

Comment: So perhaps if I create my own version of the file in the `local` structure I can change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the past for special price we have imported the same as price, thus no special_price is shown anywhere since it's the same. It seems to work, though I can't say it feels like the soundest of solutions.

Comment: Importing a past expiration date also works. But special price is just what I chose as an example. We also need to remove other data such as from dropdown/multiselect attributes for example.